# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError When call service

Tags: android

When i run my project from eclipse its working perfectly.

After created signed apk, i've tested on my device. its throws below exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.rvg.app.aws.RegisterService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2529)
```

My SplashScreen class

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity {

    private boolean isDestroyed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spashscreen);

                 startRegisterService();

        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,4000l);          
    }

    private void startRegisterService(){
        if(!MyApplication.getSnsPreference().isRegistered()){
            startService(new Intent(this, RegisterService.class));
    }
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == 1 && !isDestroyed){
                Intent intent;


                if(MyApplication.getUserPrefs().isLoggedIn()){
                    intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                }
                else{
                    intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                }

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        };      
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        isDestroyed = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and my RegisterService class

```
public class RegisterService extends Service{

    private PushRegister mRegister;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        super.onCreate();
        mRegister = new PushRegister(this);
        startRegister();
    }   

    private void startRegister(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return mRegister.registerSns();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                stopSelf();
            }

        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

How to solve this.?
When run from eclipse there is no problem. After signed apk i've loaded on sd card and installed. When open the app it crash.

What is the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Yes Mighter,. -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

Comment: Most people who have the same problem claim to be using NDK.

Comment: @Mighter hi. its working after disable the proguard.

Comment: @Mighter but how to apply proguard?

Comment: The stack that you have posted would appear to be from Eclipse catching the exception. Run past this point to allow the exception to be logged to LogCat. Then, examine LogCat and look for the nested "Caused by" exception and its portion of the stack trace.

Comment: +1 to @CommonsWare. If it's really the Proguard issue, we need to know what's the source of exception. Maybe you need to keep an additional class.